# Error:Could not find com.google.gms: google-services:4.3.15?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

I am attempting to add Firebase Auth to my Android application. When I run the application, I receive the following error message:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15:.
     Required by:
         project :
```

I already tried updating flutter, dart, and AndroidStudio. Here is a snippet of my `build.gradle` (root):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is a snippet from the `build.gradle` (modules):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Lastly, here is my `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
name: app_layout
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.6 <3.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^1.0.0
  firebase_core: ^2.13.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.6.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/
```

I also added the `google-service.json` to the app directory.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have a typo.

`classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15'`
Should be
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'`

Note the `gms.google` -> `gms:google`.

Refer to [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gms/google-services/4.3.15).

Comment: Thank you ! This fixed my issue. Seems like the google instruction is wrong.

Comment: @BabouG Do you have a link to the google instructions? We should probably fix it if it's wrong.

Comment: Sorry I mean in the firebase instruction. If you add a android app to your project, you have this instruction page, where you can download the google-services.json

Comment: Here is a link to the screenshot https://i.ibb.co/fqqZmKR/firebase.png @justhecuke

Comment: @BabouG the en version seems to be fine. https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add-config-file

Comment: @justhecuke no it's not. it still displays with a period instead of colon

Comment: @FreTimmerman you're right. my eyes must not have worked right the last time I checked. I'll see if I can't get it fixed. It's a bit sad that this question and answer is so popular when it's a simple documentation bug.

Answer (score 4):

1. Add the following code in the `build.gradle` file.

   ```
   apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
   classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15")
   ```
2. plugin should have `gms.google` and classpath should have `gms:google` module in it.
3. Move `google-service.json` to app directory.

This solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Moving to old version work for me.
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'`