# > Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15:. Required by: project :

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Facing this Error while linking console project for firbase operation:

> Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15:.
> Required by:
> project :

Each & everything is fine but maybe a new update let me to this issue.

1. Google services file is in the exact directory
2. Classpath is perfect:
   e.g:

   dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
   classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
   classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15'
   }

Plugins are in the perfect location:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:Could not find com.google.gms: google-services:4.3.15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76498771/errorcould-not-find-com-google-gms-google-services4-3-15)

Answer (score 4):

You just have to change the
`classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15'`

To
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'`

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Error:Could not find com.google.gms: google-services:4.3.15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76498771/errorcould-not-find-com-google-gms-google-services4-3-15), there seems to be a typo. I have done this and it fixed my error.

Comment: Thanks buddy, it was exactly that issue. But I thank it was flutter new version which leads to generating incorrect classpath.