# configuring my flutter project with firebase not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm trying to configure my project with the firebase and i'm getting this error :
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15:.
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1,

I followed all the steps (gradle fills) , added the the firebase fill and tried everything possible still not working , can anyone help me please ?

even tho i have old project working but the new one not working

I followed the steps of configuring the firebase , my flutter version is the last one even the android studio

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that the following line :

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```

has been added to the **root** *build.gradle*,  in the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // Other classpath
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    // Other classpath
}
```

Tip: To properly configure Firebase for Flutter, you can also use **flutterfire_cli**. You can find more info about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android

Answer (score 0):

As car_tor mentioned this is the reason but furthermore there is a typo as explained in the post: [Error:Could not find com.google.gms: google-services:4.3.15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76498771/errorcould-not-find-com-google-gms-google-services4-3-15)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question of [Error Could not find com.google.gms:google-services 4.3.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76498771/errorcould-not-find-com-google-gms-google-services4-3-15)

You have a typo in your build.gradle file

in your dependencies, it should be

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
```